# amp-list trigger AMP.pushState

Tags: amp-html

I have a checkout page with one input where customer type a discount code and then we retrieve a discount_value from a remote URL using amp-list. I need to push this discount_value to AMP state so I can do the math `product_price - discount_value`.

Any tip how I can reach this result?

Example code:

```
  <amp-state id="order_atts">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "product_price": "100"
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
  <input type="text" name="discount_coupon" on="change:AMP.pushState({discount_coupon: event.value ? event.value : ''})">
  <amp-list [src]="url + discount_coupon">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      {{#data}}
        <p [text]="order.atts_product_price - discount_value"></p>
      {{/data}}
    </template>
  </amp-list>
```

Comment: check this out: https://blog.amp.dev/2020/07/21/the-value-of-amp-list-initialization-from-state/

Comment: Nice, should resolve our problem. Thanks